# Create a new vector with some indices, potentially non-consecutive, dropped

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<int>` of a certain size, and two numbers `int a` and `int b`, which could be non-consecutive. My intention is to get a new vector which has the same entries as the original, except for the indices `a` and `b`, which should be dropped. I need both vectors for further calculations.

At the moment I'm doing the following:

```
std::vector<int> old_vector = ...;
int a = ...;
int b = ...;

std::vector<int> new_vector;   
for (int i = 0; i < old_vector.size(); i++) {
  if (i != a && i != b) {
    new_vector.push_back(old_vector[i]);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [`vector::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), which has an overload for inserting a range of values. You can replace your manual loop with 3 `insert()` calls.

Comment: Or, since you are passing in the input `vector` *by value*, you could simply [`erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) the 2 elements from it and then return it as-is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `vector::insert()` seems fine, but it means I have to add an extra check on whether `a<b` or vice-versa. Also, I would actually rather not use a function at all (see my edited OP). So both options don't seem more concise than the for-loop after all.

Comment: What's wrong with using a function?

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way is using [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with a lambda as the predicate.

In general you want to use functions from the standard library (STL) to express your solutions, if possible. The advantage is that everyone familiar with the STL knows what the function does and immediately understands what you are trying to do.

However as is your solution is perfectly valid.